# Menu getting closed on two clicks in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to make my menu off when click anywhere else in the window.
Here is the JS function I have written.

```
  $document.on('click', menuClickHandler);
     this.$onDestroy = function (){$document.off('click');}

              function menuClickHandler(event) {
            var target = event.target;
            if (!target.className.includes("icon-more more-icon")) {
                self.isMenuOpen = false;
            }
        }
```

Code is working but menu gets closed when clicked outside for two times.
I want to close the menu on a single click when clicked outside.
Please help !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20212285/3191896

Comment: @JossefHarush :In the above code , I should unbind it after making my variable false. Isnt it ?

Comment: @JossefHarush: As I am new , can u please tell how to do this without makin a directive ? from above code.Thanks