# How can I set a variable when clicking anywhere in the browser window?

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown menu on my site that is controlled by `ng-show`. When the user clicks on a button they see the dropdown. When they click again, the dropdown is hidden:

```
<div class="button" ng-click="show = !show">Click Me</div>
<div ng-show="show" ng-init="show = false">
    <div>You can see me now!</div>
</div>
```

This works fine. But, what I want is for `show` to be set to false if the user clicks anywhere in the window that is not the div with class "button". How can I achieve this?

Comment: You will need to play with angular directives http://stackoverflow.com/a/16742128/484894

Answer (score 1):

## Quick/easy way

The quickest/easiest way to do this would be to put your cancellation code (`ng-click="show=false"`) on the `body` element, and then add [`$event.stopPropagation()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation) to the existing ng-click.  This way, any time you click on the button, since the click event is prevented from propagating upward, the cancellation code wouldn't fire.  Clicking anywhere else, though, would fire the `ng-click` on the `body`, so that the cancellation code will run. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abeluga/P2PP8/) that does this.

## More 'Angular' way

I think a slightly "better" or "more angular" way to do get the same result would be to create a new `click-off` directive that can sit alongside ng-click.  The new directive could (a) register *another* click handler on the target element which would stop propagation, and (b) register a click handler on the `body` element to fire whatever cancellation code you need.  [Here's a fiddle for that approach](http://jsfiddle.net/abeluga/Wnx5F/).

Comment: `click-off` looks interesting, but `$event.stopPropagation()` is IMHO a bad idea (which I'm unfortunately also using). Just try to use two such elements, open the first and click on the second. Now, both are open as the click gets stopped.

Comment: @anandthakker Your first fiddle link's broken. Can you update it please?

Answer (score 1):

### In this solution:

- I assume you use jQuery
- I haven't tested it yet.
- I use an answer from here: [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

#### Create a directive that binds to document click events.

```
app.directive('clickOnlyHere',function(){

  return {
    scope: {
      clickOnlyHere: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var clickHandler = function(event){
        // we need to check if the click is within our element ( or its decedents).
        var inside = (element[0] === event.target) || 
                     $(event.target).parents().index(element) !== -1;

        var show = inside ? !scope.clickOnlyHere : false;
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.clickOnlyHere = show;
        });
      }

      $(document).on('click', clickHandler);

      // must remove the click handler after our scope is destroyed.
      scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
        $(document).off('click', clickHandler);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

#### Use it like so:

```
<div class="button" click-only-here="show">Click Me</div>
<div ng-show="show" ng-init="show = false">
    <div>You can see me now!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `scope.$on('$destroy', ...`?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div customDropdown>
  <h4>Click here to see dropdown</h4>
  <ul ng-show="dropdownVisible">
    <li ng-click="doSomething()">Item #1</li>
    <li ng-click="doSomething()">Item #2</li>
    <li ng-click="doSomething()">Item #3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Simple directive:

```
app.directive('customDropdown', ['$document', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, el) {

      // Switch dropdown visibility by clicking on 'target' element
      el.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        scope.dropdownVisible = !scope.dropdownVisible;
      });

      // Hide dropdown if clicked somewhere 'outside'
      $document.on('click', function(event) {
        scope.dropdownVisible = false;
        return $document.off('click', event);
      });

    }
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //your code
  });
```

Comment: This question was asked 6 years ago. Can you please provide some context rather than just code?

Comment: Hello David, if you want to set any variable or call any method when clicking anywhere in the browser window you can add $window.addEventListener of the top of your controller.whenever you click anywhere in browser your code will execute. and you can also get an event (like 'e') as an argument of this method.