# Close dropdown menus on click on other menu item or body (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone help me? I have various dropdown menus on my application and I'am trying to close them on click on other menu items and on click on body. I'am using angular.js without jQuery.

html

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController as controller">
<div class="select-box">
    <div class="select-box-field" ng-click="dropdown = !dropdown;">
        <span>Menu Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="select-box-field-dropdown" ng-class="{ 'is-active':dropdown }">
        <span>Dropdown menu Item 1</span>
        <span>Dropdown menu Item 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('application');

  app.controller('SomeController', someCtrl);

  function someCtrl () { 

    var vm = this;
    vm.dropdown = false;

  };
})();
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aafvxmbn/2/

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aafvxmbn/2/

Comment: This is probably the best solution I found:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068955/how-can-i-set-a-variable-when-clicking-anywhere-in-the-browser-window/21069377#21069377

Comment: The best solution would be to use the ui.bootstrap dropdown http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

You can call the same unction from the container and call `$event.stopPropagation()`

See this updated [fiiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/aafvxmbn/64/)
You can set dropdown value in `ng-click`

```
<div class="select-box-field" ng-click="change(1)">
```

or

```
<div class="select-box-field" ng-click="change(1)">
```

and in controller 
 the function change()

```
.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope, $element)
  {
      $scope.dropdown=0;
      $scope.change = function(a) {

            $scope.dropdown=a;
      }

  })
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/aafvxmbn/64/) for full working demo

Comment: This works for the dropdown toggle only, but a click on body will not close the dropdown. By the way. <ou can't close the dropdown on click any more. But Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Create a *directive* for your dropdown which also handles the click event. In your case it will just set `dropdown = false;`. For this, it will bind two event handlers: one on your *html* and another on the `elem` itself. Something like this:

```
myApp.directive('clickOutside', function() {
    return function(scope, elem) {
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
        x.addEventListener('click', function() {
            dropdown = false;
            scope.$apply();            
        });
        elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
});
```

It may not work like this, you need to add the directive to your markup and pass `dropdown` to the *directive*. Make a fiddle to make it easier to help you.

For more info about detecting outside clicks read [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Please see the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10442/):

Comment: I've made a fiddle, but it does not work. Do you have an idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/aafvxmbn/6/

Comment: try to tweak this fiddle a little bit by your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10442/