# click on body to hide element angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use 2 ng-click to try to do a toggle effect. first one bind to says a button, the other one used on body tag. I expect when I click the button my stuff shows up and when I click anywhere on the body, my stuff hide.

But angularjs seem unlike jquery. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/KG4b9B1gac53a8JkRBvu?p=preview
What is the approach to achieve that?

Comment: This is quite similar to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385614/angular-js-closing-with-click-anywhere-but-on-the-element

Comment: @ZlatinZlatev it doesn't bind the entire body.. with jquery that's so easy..

Comment: What if you use an overlay div and resize it to cover the body?

Answer (score 0):

the poblem here is, that clicking the button also triggers clicking the body. here a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HlZUnAa59M6eW6Pe1aMa?p=preview) to show what i mean.

you could add your click event to the body after clicking the button.

Comment: what you repeat my question? u stole my plunkr buddy ><

Comment: i pasted the wrong link, but edited it 2 seconds late. sorry about that. i didn't repeated your question. i told you, this wont work because of the "doubled" trigger on click. so again: "you could add your click event to the body after clicking the button" .. better, buddy? ;p