# After click anywhere removed the class with angularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Let's say i have a search box and i want to display it after user click on button . so far so good .
but i want to add another feature , when user click anywhere search box go away .
How can i do this with AngularJs ?

this is my code :
**HTML**

```
  <button class="btn btn-info " ng-click="addStyle()" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i>

            Search</button>
  <input type="text"  placeholder="Type" class="{{noneStyle}} {{visibleStyle}}">
```

**Angular**

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope,$http){


    $scope.noneStyle = "noneVisible";
    $scope.addStyle = function(){
        $scope.noneStyle = "visibleStyle";
    }

})
```

any idea ?
Thx in advance

Comment: Check out this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931369/click-everywhere-but-here-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend use ng-if instead

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope,$http){

   $scope.visible = true;
    $scope.changeStatus = function(){
        $scope.visible = !$scope.visible; 
    }
    $scope.hideAll= function(){
      $scope.visible=false;
    }

})
```

HTML

```
<div class="well" ng-controller="MyController">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="checked" ng-click="changeStatus()" ng-blur="hideAll()">BUTTON</button>
    <hr/>
       {{visible}}
       <input type="text"  placeholder="Type" ng-if="visible">  
</div>
```

look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dupk2ytv/)

try it out!

Comment: thank you , i've added your code but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-blur/ng-focus to achieve this.

I demonstrate a simple code over here. http://jsfiddle.net/lookman/1Lp95or0/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

    $scope.visible = true;
    $scope.changeStatus = function(){
        $scope.visible = !$scope.visible; 
    }
    $scope.hideAll= function(){
      $scope.visible=false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    
<button ng-disabled="checked" 
    ng-click="changeStatus()">Click to show/hide the input box</button>
    <hr/>
    <p>Current visible status: {{visible}}</p>
   <input type="text"  placeholder="Type" ng-show="visible" ng-blur="hideAll()">  
       
</div>
    </div>
```

Note that in this example, you need to click on input box first before clicking elsewhere to hide it. I hope this is what are you looking for and this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-blur` directive to update your model when the user clicks somewhere else:

```
<button class="btn btn-info " ng-click="addStyle()" ng-blur="removeStyle()">
```

Comment: Thank you , i've added it and add removeStyle function but nothing happend .

Comment: It does work on my example, maybe your removeStyle function is doing something wrong? Check that example: http://jsfiddle.net/floribon/kLrc2Ltr/

Comment: yes , and the reason that code does'nt work is angular version , ng-focus work with 1.2 version

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using standard JavaScript, registering an event listener once the search box is displayed and unregistering it, as soon as the user has clicked anywhere:

```
$scope.addStyle = function()
{
    $scope.noneStyle = "visibleStyle";

    // register event listener
    document.addEventListener("click", hideSearchBox);
}

function hideSearchBox()
{
    // set style to hide search box
    $scope.noneStyle = "noneVisible";
    // unregister event listener
    document.removeEventListener("click", hideSearchBox);
}
```

I'm not sure if there is a more Anuglar-way of doing it. To do so, you would need to register something on document level, as you want the search box to be hidden if you click anywhere. And "anywhere" might not be where the Angular root scope is registered..