# Angular: simulate mouseleave on touch devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, touch

I am trying to refactor our app for touch devices. I am stuck on trying to simulate mouse leave behavior. The only thing that I have found that relates to the problem I am trying to solve is [Click everywhere but here event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931369/click-everywhere-but-here-event) but it seems kinda hammajang to me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at `ngTouch`?

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-on-mobile.html

What exactly do you mean for a "mouseleave" on a touch device?

Comment: I've looked at it and tried ngClick to no avail. I want to be able to touch anywhere else and have that touch fire behavior that ng-mouseleave does on non-touch devices - specifically - conditionally set classes via ng-class to hide elements.