# AngularJS click anywhere but here with HTML5Mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I'm using the following directive:

```
app.directive("ngOutside", function($document, $rootScope){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl){

      elem.bind("click", function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
      });

      $document.bind("click", function(){
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
          $rootScope.nav = false;
          $rootScope.aside.on = false;
        });
      });

    }
  }
});
```

Now I apply this in my HTML like so:

```
<nav ng-outside>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Originally I was using hashbang mode and the directive worked fine. Now I am using HTML5 mode and the `e.stopPropagation` is stopping Angular working out the routing when one of the nav links is clicked. Instead, the browser now treats the link normally and does a full page reload to the location.

If I remove the following, it solves the problem but the directive no longer does it's job:

```
elem.bind("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

How can I implement the 'click anywhere but here' type directive without breaking links in HTML5 mode?

Comment: Have you specified a base href in your index file? ```<base href="/">```

Comment: @Duncan Yeh that's in there. I don't think the issue is with using the `HTML5mode` because when I remove the `e.stopPropagation` part of that directive, route changes work perfectly.

Comment: Does `e.preventDefault()` not achieve the desired effect?

Comment: @Mikey no the e.stopPropagation is used to stop the directive firing when clicking on the directive element. The idea was taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931369/click-everywhere-but-here-event

Comment: So just to understand the use case here, for I am wracking my brain trying to understand, you are telling angular to not allow a user to click on the nav, but you still want the links in the nav element to accept clicks?

Comment: @acg no the concept is, when the user clicks on any element except within the nav, a function fires.

Comment: Thanks, I know you may not like this answer and you probably already did it and were hoping for clarity on this, but I think you may need to move the ngOutside to a div that contains all the other content.

Comment: @acg Yeh that's the current workaround I've done.